# CiviContribute: change "from" email address for thank-you letters

Tags: civicontribute, email

I'm using CiviCRM 4.7.27 and am trying to change the "from" address used for thank-you emails generated from CiviContribute. The workflow we are using apparently has no option to choose the email sender and the emails are sent with a "from" address of the current CiviCRM user! NOTE: This workflow is not from the "Mailings" menu. The procedure I am using is:

1. Search for contributions from the menu: Contributions -> Find Contributions
2. Select search options (typically: select "No" for the "Thank-you sent?" option to find all contributions that have not been acknowledged with a thank-you letter). Click "Search"
3. Select all found contributions by clicking the check-box next to each one
4. Select "Thank-you letters, print or email" from the "Actions" menu. This leads to the "Print/Merge Document" screen
5. Select "Send emails where possible. Generate PDFs for contacts who cannot receive email" from the "Print and Email Options" selector. Also select the "thank you letter" template and click "Make thank you letters". NOTE: There is NO option to select the email sender from this page!

Result: email is sent, but the "from" address is the email address of the current CiviCRM user!

Is this a bug or am I missing something? I see that from the "Mailings" menu, I can create a mailing and select the "from" email address. However, there doesn't seem to be a Mailings workflow which allows me to send a tailored thank-you to donors who have not been acknowledged.

Comment: I removed my answer as I clearly hadn't read your question properly. Apologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick look at the 'Thank-you Letter for Contributions (PDF)' page suggests that you are not missing something, and that this is not possible at the moment.

I wouldn't call it a bug, I would call it a missing feature, but that is somewhat academic / pendantic :)

If you did want to be able to select a person, as you can when sending other mailings, you would need to add this feature. Either by asking someone to do it for you, or coding it yourself (not sure if you are a coder, Noky).

If you want to go down the first route, you can find a list of people that could help you do this here: https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors

Comment: Thanks! I think the workaround will be to setup a login for a "donation officer" user, whose address we want to use for sending thank-you mailings.

Comment: Nice work around. Sorry it is not possible right now!